# Order of declared variables with printf (assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

Here is my working code:

```
.section .data
prompt:
    .asciz "Please input value:\n"
input:
    .asciz "%d"
output:
    .asciz "output: %d\n"
integer:
    .int
.section .text
.globl  main
main:
    nop

    pushl $prompt
    call printf
    addl $8, %esp

    pushl $integer
    pushl $input
    call scanf
    addl $8, %esp

    movl integer, %ecx
    pushl %ecx
    pushl $output
    call printf
    add $8, %esp

    pushl $0
    call exit
```

Why is it that if I change the order of:

```
input:
    .asciz "%d"
output:
    .asciz "output: %d\n"
integer:
    .int
```

to (where `integer` is above its `input`)

```
integer:
    .int
input:
    .asciz "%d"
output:
    .asciz "output: %d\n"
```

...then it no longer prints out your scanned integer? Is it because we reference $integer first, when we push it onto the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually specify a value for `.int`, otherwise it won't do anything. So in the second case, your integer (which is 4 bytes) overlaps the `input` and the start of `output` too. Assuming you input a number that has a zero in the most significant byte (that is any non-negative number less than `2^24`) you will effectively truncate the output string to zero length.

To fix it you can just do `.int 0` or declare your integer in the `.bss` section for example using `.lcomm integer, 4`.

Comment: If you could slightly clarify, I would like to know why the 4-bytes overlap in the second case, but don't if I was to declare zero. Is it that the zero allocates the 4-bytes beforehand then starts the next 32-bit memory address for `input` after the 4-bytes, otherwise the memory address of `input` is directly after the 32-bit address of `integer`?

Comment: Yes, if you don't allocate a value, then `integer` is going to have the same address as `input`.